# How to run ElasticSearch on user's devices AND keep ElasticSearch server safe?

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch

Writing a mobile app with `Firebase` being my backend, also using ES to power my search. I'm completely new to ES.

Suppose each user can publish articles, each of which contains some number of tags, which denotes what this article is about, kind of like questions asked here. Users can search for articles, with tags, and articles containing that tag will be displayed. I manage to do that with `Cloud Function`, so, the `Cloud Function` basically looks like this:

```
exports.articleSearch = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { tag } = req.query;

    const ElasticSearchConfig = {
        uri: '..<my elastic cloud url>/articles/article/_search...',
        method: 'GET',
        body: ...,
        json: true,
        auth: {
            username: '...<my elastic cloud username>...',
            password: '...<my elastic cloud password>...'
        }
    };

    // If succeeds, send results back to user, if not, send error back
    request(ElasticSearchConfig).then((results) => ...)
        .catch((error) => ...);
});
```

This works, however, it's a bit slow, because I'm not running ElasticSearch on user's devices, instead, through a cloud function. But if I do run the above code on user's devices, you noticed `auth` property of `ElasticSearchConfig` object, I'm basically giving everybody permissions to access and manipulate my ES server. How can I run the above code on user's devices and at the same time, prevent them from reading or writing anything without proper permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no secure way to do what your asking. Even if it was possible, you don't want that kind of processing client side draining the battery, especially on mobile. Your slow response from cloud functions may be caused from the function entering a timeout state, meaning it hasn't been called in a while.